# Change the output format of a string

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
string str = "a_b_c_ _ _abc_ _ _ _abcd";
```

Now, str has to be converted to string of this format:

```
[a][b][c][_ _abc][_ _ _abcd]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any pattern behind this? Because I can not really detect it.

Comment: @Grumbler85 As far as I can see: remove the underscore behind each character, and enclose the character(s) with all leading underscores in brackets.

Comment: @Herdo ...and the very first `a` (or the last `abcd`, if you mean following when you say 'leading')?  No leading underscore.  You could come up with several sets of rules like yours, all of which require arbitrary `except` clauses for the edge cases.  Unless OP tells us what the *actual* pattern is, there is no way to answer this.

Comment: @J... OP, yep, but he didn't edit. Only enclose the leading underscores, if there are any. Same applies to "b" and "c". Underscore has been removed, due to it's trailing on "a". So "b" gets enclosed by its own. It's a simple algorithm...

Comment: @Herdo - it's not that simple.  You're suggesting a one-to-one correspondence.  It's not true.  Four underscores are missing.  Five groups are in brackets.  There's a missing rule to explain why that happened.  More to the point, your suspected pattern is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit quick'n'dirty, but you should get the idea.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(([_ ]*[a-z]+)_ ?)+([_ ]*[a-z]+)");
    string str = "a_b_c_ _ _abc_ _ _ _abcd";

    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    // 2 - because of specific regex construction
    for (int i = 2; i < match.Groups.Count; i++) {

        foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[i].Captures)
            Console.Write("[{0}]", capture.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

https://ideone.com/m3Vhci

```
stdout
[a][b][c][_ _abc][_ _ _abcd]
```

Comment: Thanks Spook. It seems quite easy using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
string res = "[" + Regex.Replace(str, @"([^_\s])_\s*", "$1][") + "]";
```